# Rendering PostGIS layers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, rendering, ubuntugis

I am running QGIS Desktop 3.18.2 on Ubuntu, but I have observed this issue on other operating systems.

When I query a relatively small table (~300 simple polygons) from PostGIS on a remote server, it takes time to load the data as a layer through the DB Manager.   When the data are loaded as a  "QueryLayer", zooming in and out becomes so painfully slow that data exploration becomes virtually impossible.

However, when I save the QueryLayer as a geojson file to my local drive, rendering becomes lightning fast and the issue is fixed.  Is it expected behavior that data originating from external database connections render slowly?  If read/write operations are not being performed, why is rendering so slow on datasets that have been fully uploaded (in other words, when the read operation has finished)?  Is there a setting in QGIS that would bring the layer into local memory and alleviate the need for saving layers as local files?

Comment: I think that every time you pan or zoom the query is run again. I usually create a temporary table and then delete when I'm done (`create table abc_temp as`)

Comment: make sure that the table has a spatial index

Comment: It could depend on the speed of the server hosting your database or the connection speed between your computer and DB.

Comment: You could also try creating a materialized view from your query. Like commented earlier, the query is running every time you do something on your project which makes it very slow.